How to use PDType1Font in apache fontbox in java?
enter image description here
I tired to create a simple pdf manupilate toll using java. first I need to create a new pdf. I have install maven packges also
in this code, I tried use PDType1font but it alwasy return "cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable COURIER
location: class PDType1Font" error. I've changed font also. I use pdfbox 3.0.3 and fontbox 3.0.3

use new PDType1Font(FontName.COURIER);
